# remove termination symbol from xml

Tags: java, xml

I'm trying to convert json into xml. It gets converted but not a validated xml. The only problem is In xml (;) symbol is coming at the end. I want that symbol to be removed before i get final xml.

Here its my code, and tell me what should I do or add to remove that symbol

```
output_row.Body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-15\"?>\n<root>" + org.json.XML.toString(jsonFileObject ).replaceAll("48x48>", "tag48x48>").replaceAll("16x16>", "tag16x16>").replaceAll("32x32>", "tag32x32>").replaceAll("24x24>", "tag24x24>") + "</root>";
```

Please help me !!

Comment: What do you know about string manipulation? If it's at the end, just remove the last character from the string

Comment: @Arc676, I'm automating this process in etl, And upto receiving xml file all is working fine but when I use that xml it shows error for further process. So for that xml should be validated and because of the symbol am not able to proceed further. So I'm trying to add some extra code where I'm converting json to xml.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really sure, you always have a `;` at the end of the xml, just remove the last character from it's string representation, with `String#substring` method after the last `replaceAll` call:

```
String xmlStr = org.json.XML.toString(jsonFileObject);
output_row.Body = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"ISO-8859-15\"?>\n<root>"  
    + xmlStr.replaceAll("48x48>", "tag48x48>")
            .replaceAll("16x16>", "tag16x16>")
            .replaceAll("32x32>", "tag32x32>")
            .replaceAll("24x24>", "tag24x24>")
            .substring(0, xmlStr.length()-1)  //<- here is what you need
    + "</root>";
```

Comment: @drill yes, just one redundant `+` added whil formatted the code. updated